# Multi Keyword search on multi-column sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to make a multi-keyword search on my website.

I want to find every post who contains A AND B.

For example if I search "**A** **B**"

I should find these post:

> Title: **A**cd **B**afd
>   Content: zzzzzz

And also this one

> Title: ddddd
>
> Content: **A**ttt**B**cccd

But not this one

> Title: **A**ttttt
>
> Content: **B**wwwww

Because the title or the content doesn't have all the keyword I'm looking for.

For now I have made this request which is working

```
keys = params[:search].split(' ')
Article.where((["title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?"] * keys.size).join(' AND '), *(keys.map { |key| ["%#{key}%", "%#{key}%"] }.flatten)).where(activate: true).order(created_at: :desc)
```

But the AND is acting same with a OR. It show me the 3 examples I gave.

Do you think I should separate it in two request ?

RAILS 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explain it, then title should contain `A` and `B`, or content should contain `A` and `B`.

You can try with:

```
Article
  .where("title LIKE '%A%' AND title LIKE '%B%'")
  .or(Article.where("content LIKE '%A%' AND content LIKE '%B%'"))
```

I'm hardcoding the values for LIKE here, maybe you can add an example of what you're using to update this.

Comment: I have transform my first sql request with your answer which look like this now : ```Article.where((["title LIKE ?"] * keys.size).join(' AND '), *(keys.map { |key| "%#{key}%"}.flatten)).where(activate: true).or(Article.where((["content LIKE ?"] * keys.size).join(' AND '), *(keys.map { |key| "%#{key}%"}.flatten)).where(activate: true)).order(created_at: :desc)``` and it work perfectly thank you

Comment: For that, you can use `flat_map` instead of `map { ... }.flatten`.